# How to get a current years' monthly sum of amount and display it in consoleTv bar chart

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have tried with few queries. But it doesn't work form me.

```
$amount = DB::select('select month(created_at) as month, 
sum(amount) as total_amount 
from orders 
group by month(created_at)');
```

I am getting values like

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#2186 ▼
    +"month": 5
    +"total_amount": 720.0
  }
  1 => {#2187 ▼
    +"month": 6
    +"total_amount": 720.0
  }
]
```

But getting error while using this data with consoleTv.

Error: **Call to a member function filter() on array**

Comment: *"Error: Call to a member function filter() on array"* i that case your question is missing that code, we need to see it.  But it would make sense as the result is a array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```html
$data = orders::select(
                \DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as months'),
                \DB::raw("Sum(amount) as sums")
            )
            ->groupBy('months')
            ->orderBy('months','asc')
            ->get();

        $chart = Charts::database($data, 'bar', 'highcharts')
            ->title("Monthly Amount")
            ->elementLabel("Total Amount")
            ->dimensions(300, 500)
            ->responsive(false)
   ->groupBy('months')
   ->values($data->pluck('sums'));
```